# Suggest SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display particular column of my table in android activity text view.
My table name is Class.
There are two columns 1) Class Name and 2) NoStudent.
I have tried this:

```
select * from Class where column +ClassName+;
```

& lot other formats but doesn't working.
Give proper query format & reference link from where I can get other correct format.
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `SELECT * FROM` because it means you no-longer have a predictable resultset. If your schema changes and you're using ordinal column referencing in your data-readers then they'll break.

Anyway, like so:

```
SELECT "className", "noStudent" FROM "Class" WHERE "className" = 'Databases 101'
```

Note my use of `"` (double quote) to escape column and table names, which is SQLite's syntax for escaping. Do not confuse it with the `'` (single quote) used to delimit strings.

If you add more terms to your query it will get long on one line. SQL ignores linebreaks and I prefer to format queries like so:

```
SELECT
    "className", "noStudent"
FROM
     "Class"
WHERE
    "className" = 'Databases 101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT classname, nostudent FROM Class WHERE classname = 'myclass'
```

Check out the [w3schools site for SQL syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp).